# ubuntu ngnix aws lightsail server cant able to access via putty

Tags: server, ssh, firewall, nginx, ssl

After changing the firewall settings in the server. I cant able to access via putty.

I tried to install ssl certificate, where I supposed to change the firewall settings.

I also tried rebooted the server. I cant able to access the server via the inbuilt web console.

Comment: If you are unable to access the system via SSH or the web console because the firewall is preventing connections, then you have only two options: (1) hack the system to regain access [hard] (2) fire up a new server and restore from backup [easy].

Comment: this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lightsail-resolve-ssh-console-errors/ helps me to do that